# How to get all dynamic images from folder to the website in the quickest way possible?

Tags: c#, jquery, css, hosting, imagehandler

We have launched our new website. Now we are facing problem with page loading. As there are many images, the page is taking much time to load. All the images are dynamic and are saved in folder. We are retrieving them from folder. We did the site in C#.Net. We used handler for JS files to load. Is there any handler to get all the images from the saved folder in the quickest time possible. We are running out of time. Please respond at the earliest. Please check the requests from website in the link given below:
http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/9b2ri/www.f1usavisa.com

Comment: Look into caching (cache)

Comment: But Cache will work after the first load, if we are not wrong! So how to do that when the page load for the first time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the power of Jquery. May the following idea can help you.

Let us assume that you have 100 images in the folder.

1. Build only first 10 images while responding and keep the remaining 90 images path as delimeted string as hidden field in the page.
2. Using Jquery on document complete, loop through the delimeted image file path and dynamically append the the Images.In this way the initial load time will be only for 10 images and the user will be seeing the page immedietley.

Hope the above will help you.